# how to mock QueueItems[] using mockito?

Tags: mockito

```
QueueItems[] items = ....
```

how i can mock object for QueueItems[] using mockito?

i tried : ArrayList workItems = mock(ArrayList.class); 
          QueueItems = mock(QueueItems.class);

but not working.

Comment: Are you trying to mock an array? Why not just use a real array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to customly create an array of items, you should create such an array and then insert mocks into the array. You should not try to mock an array, as this is core Java implementation.

Also, `List`s are better to use as they allow more flexibility. An example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Mock
    private QueueItem item1;

    private List<QueueItem> items;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        items = new ArrayList<QueueItem>();
        // Your mocked QueueItem is the first entry in the list
        items.add(item1);
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        invokeSomeMethodWithList(items);
        Mockito.verify(item1).someMethod();
    }
}
```